# Unique Web Page Url after every transaction

Tags: php, javascript

I am building a book business website.

When the customer wants to download the book, first he has to pay the bill and then after the successful payment, the page redirects to the download page where the customer can download that book.

Here my question is how to create a unique web page address(for example : if the 1st customer pays the bill then the download page appears say (ex:www.downloadthebook.com/1) and if the 2nd customer pays the bill then the download page has to appear like this, say (www.downloadthebook.com/2).

And also if the customer copy the url of that download page and loads in the new tab. the url should not work. The download page only works if the payment is succesful.

Answer (score 0):

Magento by default support downloadable product which have out of the box support for this.